# How to access the Cisco Catalyst 2960 Series switch port mirroring webpage/admin interface?

Tags: cisco, switch, monitoring, mirror

I have read the tutorials about how to send several command lines to setup port mirroring (e.g. source port, destination port). But before sending commands to the switch, I need a administration interface, such as cmd window, or web management platform.

Hence, where I can access that admin interface? For example, for cisco Catalyst 2960 Series switch. From the destination port connected computer/laptop? Then connect the switch's IP?

Comment: You must tell which model. Most Cisco switches have only command line interface (CLI). Some have a web interface but those are usually only a wrapper to the CLI.

Comment: catalyst 2960 series

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to the console port of the switch to configure it. Use the provided console cable. This will connect you to the CLI interface, and this is how you will initially configure the switch.

You can then configure an SVI with an IP address in a VLAN on the switch, and configure the default gateway in the same VLAN for the switch to use. You can use this address to manage the switch remotely. To use the CLI, you will also need to configure a password on the the VTY lines. The default would be to use telnet, but you can configure something else, e.g SSH, but that is more complicated, albeit more secure.

You probably want to use the CLI interface, rather than the HTTP server, to manage the switch.

Comment: Most cisco switches will use console port? I also saw HP switches use HTTP. hence, it depends on manufacturers, right?

Comment: For CLI, I can just connect a laptop to the console port, and use cmd to login, right?

Comment: The console port is a serial port, so you need a serial port or a USB to serial adapter for your PC. Once you have configured the switch to communicate on the network, you could use the HTTP server, but you may find it limiting. To have full configuration capabilities, you should use the CLI. Most network engineers use the CLI. The HTTP server can also be a security risk, and you will usually find that companies routinely disable it on Cisco devices.